# Xcode Spritekit destroy sprite on touch and create other sprites?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where the player has to touch enemy sprites to destroy them. The player is always in the middle of the screen. There are a number of different enemy types i am testing the app idea out with 2 enemy types first.

here is the code that creates the enemies.

```
func createEnemy(type:Enemies, forSpawner spawner: Int) -> SKSpriteNode?
    {

        switch type {
        case .diamond:
            enemySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Diamond")
            enemySprite.setScale(0.5)
            enemySprite.color = UIColor.green
            enemySprite.colorBlendFactor = 1
            enemySprite.name = "enemy"
            let location = targetLocation
            let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y), duration: 2.0)
            enemySprite.run(action)
        case .diamondSolid:
            enemySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "DiamondSolid")
            enemySprite.setScale(0.5)
            enemySprite.color = UIColor.purple
            enemySprite.colorBlendFactor = 1
            enemySprite.name = "enemySolid"
            let location = targetLocation
            let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y), duration: 1.0)
            enemySprite.run(action)
        }

        guard let enemyPosition = spawnArray?[spawner].position else {return nil}
        let dx = targetLocation.x - enemyPosition.x
        let dy = targetLocation.y - enemyPosition.y
        let angle = atan2(dy,dx)

        enemySprite.position.x = enemyPosition.x
        enemySprite.position.y = enemyPosition.y
        enemySprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: enemySprite.size.width, height: enemySprite.size.height))
        enemySprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
        enemySprite.zRotation = angle - 90 * degreesToRadians



        return enemySprite

    }
```

and the on touch function

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            let node = self.nodes(at: location).first

            if node?.name == "enemy"{
                node?.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
```

What i think i need to do is send a location from the touch event and send it to a new function that destroys the enemy with some emitter particle goodness to let the player know that shape is dead. Depending on type it will either destroy and add to a score or destroy, add to score and spawn a number of other enemies and move them back a certain amount before moving them towards targetLocation. Any help on how i could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i think i sorted this problem out by creating a class for the enemies itself but now i have a problem where i cant spawn an emitter as an explosion effect when each enemy is killed. i removed some code to balance out the problem but here is the code

```
import SpriteKit

enum EnemyType:Int {
    case diamond
    case triangle
    case chevron
    case elipse
    case pentagon
    case diamondSolid
    case traingleSolid
    case elipseSolid
    case pentagonSolid
}

class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {

    let type: EnemyType
    var enemyTexture:SKTexture!
    var touched = false
    init (type:EnemyType){
        self.type = type

        switch type {
        case .diamond:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "diamond")
        case .triangle:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "triangle")
        case .chevron:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "chevron")
        case .elipse:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "elipse")
        case .pentagon:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "pentagon")
        case .diamondSolid:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "diamondSolid")
        case .traingleSolid:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "triangleSolid")
        case .elipseSolid:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "elipseSolid")
        case .pentagonSolid:
            enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "pentagonSolid")

        }

        super.init(texture: enemyTexture,color:UIColor.clear, size: CGSize.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func createPhysicsBody()
    {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
        physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemyCategory
        physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.playerCategory
        physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.playerCategory
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            if let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "explosion.sks"){
            explosion.position = self.position
            self.addChild(explosion)
            self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)){
            explosion.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
        removeFromParent()
    }

}
```

at the moment all this code should be doing is removing the enemy that is touched and playing a particle emitter. am i doing something wrong?